# Solr: FileListEntityProcessor is executing sub entities multiple times

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler, dih

I have configured a dih-import.xml as shown below. The `FileListEntityProcessor` walks through some folders and then executes a XPathEntity and a DB-Entity for each file.

When I executed a full import for ~30.000 files, the import took almost 3 hours. Back to the DIH-debug console it showed me, that for the first file that was found 2 db-calls were made, for the 2nd 4, then 6, 8, ..

google didn't show me anything on this subject, so I am hoping for you  :)

Thanks in advance

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource 
        name="cr-db"
        jndiName="xyz"
        type="JdbcDataSource" />
    <dataSource 
        name="cr-xml" 
        type="FileDataSource" 
        encoding="utf-8" />


    <document name="doc">
        <entity 
            dataSource="cr-xml" 
            name="f" 
            processor="FileListEntityProcessor" 
            baseDir="/path/to/xml" 
            filename="*.xml" 
            recursive="true" 
            rootEntity="true" 
            onError="skip">
            <entity
                name="xml-data" 
                dataSource="cr-xml" 
                processor="XPathEntityProcessor" 
                forEach="/root" 
                url="${f.fileAbsolutePath}" 
                transformer="DateFormatTransformer" 
                onError="skip">
                <field column="id" xpath="/root/id" /> 

                <field column="A" xpath="/root/a" />
            </entity>

            <entity 
                name="db-data" 
                dataSource="cr-db"
                query="
                    SELECT  
                        id, b
                    FROM 
                        a_table
                    WHERE 
                        id = '${f.file}'">
                <field column="B" name="b" />
            </entity>
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

---

**EDIT**
found the problem at google, but no answer there either: http://osdir.com/ml/solr-user.lucene.apache.org/2010-04/msg00138.html

---

**and another edit**

updated solr from 3.6 to 4.1 and executed the importer. The problem still exists, only that there are not 2n (2, 4, 6, 8, ..) calls for the sub-entities anymore but only n.

Comment: Just a clarification? Are you trying to make one Solr document per file? Which would mean you only have one /root entry in it? Is that correct?

Comment: That is correct. A single Solr doc should contain `id`, `A` and `B` which is working as expected, just not in a proper time and with way to much load on the db

Answer (score 1):

If the main issue is the number of hits on the Database when you use JdbcDataSource, you may try switching to [CachedSqlEntityProcessor](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#CachedSqlEntityProcessor).

You may also want to track [SOLR-2943](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2943), as they want to address exactly your problem, hopefully for upcoming Solr 4.2

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Similar to the one I got here: http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/solr-dih-does-multiple-queries-for-sub-entities-tt4044522.html. That is no solution however, as for each file there is 1 db-entry (1:1), so there is nothing that could be cached. One processor (i believe it's it FileListEntity) just does too many calls:  (n * ( n + 1)) / 2

Comment: The same happens with the files that are xpathed btw. They are called n times, where n is the position within the return set of the FileListEntityProcessor

Comment: I noticed that you use *cr-xml* dataSource in both outer and inner entities. Can you check what happens if you have two different data sources there. It is possible that the datasource gets reinitialized in the inner entity and somehow breaks the outer entity looping. Just double the dataSource definition and give them different names.

Comment: I tried that but unfortunately with the same outcome.. I am going for a post now even though I really would have liked to use the DIH
Thanks again

Comment: Try it again with just released 4.2. Maybe it got fixed.