# SOLR DIH multiple queries

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler, dih

### **Problem**

SOLR DIH sums up queries in each iteration. Like in third iteration following output is produced

```
"entity:us-patent-grant-xslt",
  [
    "document#3",
    [
      "query",
      "/var/www/data1/US07985001-20110726.XML",
      "query",
      "/var/www/data1/US07985001-20110726.XML",
      "query",
      "/var/www/data1/US07985001-20110726.XML",
      "time-taken",
      "0:0:0.0",
      "time-taken",
      "0:0:0.0",
      "time-taken",
      "0:0:0.0",
      null,
      "----------- row #1-------------",
      "id",
      "US7985001",
      "pub_date",
      "2011-07-26 00:00:00",
      null,
      "---------------------------------------------"
    ],
```

**Data config file**

```
<entity name="pickupdir"
        processor="FileListEntityProcessor"
        rootEntity="false"
        dataSource="null"
        fileName="^[\w\d-]+\.XML$"
        baseDir="/var/www/data1/"
        recursive="true"
        onError="skip">

            <entity name="us-patent-grant-xslt"
                   url="${pickupdir.fileAbsolutePath}"
                   xsl="data.xsl"
                   processor="XPathEntityProcessor"
                   useSolrAddSchema= "true" 
                   rootEntity="true"
                   onError="skip">

                       <field column="id" />
                       <field column="pub_date" />
           </entity>
</entity>
```

So when I bulk upload data in each iteration queries sums up and performance lags. Currently my server processes 2 docs/second.

### I am not using SQL entities, so cachedsqlentity processor can not be implemented.

### Similar problem

**[solr-dih does multiple queries for sub-entities](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/solr-dih-does-multiple-queries-for-sub-entities-td4044522.html)**

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15164166/1369473